# How do I close the window and the buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this window that has a "close" button.

[image]

When I press the "close" button, it only hides the blue window without hiding the 2 buttons in the image as well.

I want it to hide everything. I've attached the C# code from both classes and also the XAML code of all buttons.

```
  <local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="0" x:Name="leftbtn" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollLeftStyle}" Click="PageLeftButtonClick" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageLeftEnabled}"/>
  <local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="2" x:Name="right_btn" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollRightStyle}" Click="PageRightButtonClick" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageRightEnabled}"/>
```

The method that hides the buttons:

```
public partial class ImagesGrid : UserControl
{
    public ImagesGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        leftbtn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        right_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    public  void btn()
    {
        leftbtn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        right_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

The method that hides the SelectionDisplay window and the call of the `btn` method

```
private void OnCloseFullImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Always go to normal state before a transition
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    ImagesGrid img = new ImagesGrid();
    img.btn();
}
```

The place where I want to make the buttons visible

```
else if (button.Tag is WineModel)
{
    var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
    var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
    this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
    leftbtn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    right_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

EDIT:SelectionDisplay.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.SelectionDisplay"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         Background="Transparent"
         FontFamily="Segoe UI"
         FontSize="30" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="labelStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="valueStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<!--<Grid x:Name="layoutRoot">-->
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" Width="auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Image x:Name="Display" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="185" Width="293" Margin="50,0,10,0" Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Origin:" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Origin}"  Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Grapes" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Grapes}" Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Color" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Nose" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nose}" Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Price" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='C'}" Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <k:KinectCircleButton Style="{StaticResource CancelButtonStyle}" Foreground="White" Click="OnCloseFullImage"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>        
</Grid>
<!--</Grid>-->
```

Comment: System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed

Comment: @patrick, while that is normally a better choice, there are use cases for "Visibility.Hidden" either way, it won't affect the buttons visibility as noted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This code (from the close handler)

```
ImagesGrid img = new ImagesGrid();
img.btn();
```

Creates a **brand new** "ImagesGrid", then instructs it to hide. You need to get a reference to the *existing* "ImagesGrid" and invoke the `btn` method on it.

Since they are tied together, I would make the "scroll" buttons part of the same user control that contains the "close" button and avoid the issue entirely. If you really want to pass the reference around:

If your main user control has an "ImagesGrid"

```
<local:ImagesGrid Name="ScrollButtons"/>
```

Then you would write:

```
ScrollButtons.btn();
```

Now of course, this causes a problem because your other user control likely doesn't have access to "ScrollButtons" so you need to pass a reference to your "View" class (or the ScrollButtons object itself) when creating the "main" user control, etc. It gets very messy, which is why I would just combine the two!

Comment: what reference do you mean? can you explain a little more clear please?

Comment: @user3660050, added a minimal example. It starts to get long with having to pass the reference to the user control, so I noted that as well, but at least it is hopefully more clear.

Comment: and what whould combining the buttons require?
If it's easier, I'd rather use that

Comment: @user3660050 You would have a parent user control that contains the main viewing area and an "Image Grid" (or just the two buttons if the user control isn't gaining you anything). Then when you hide the parent user control (using your close button) everything hides.

Comment: i've edited the main post and added the xaml for the SelectionDisplay class; is it ok like this?

Comment: @user3660050 Looks fine, you would add the "Scroll" controls to that user control, and then the hide should work automatically.

Comment: i've added this code <local:ImagesGrid Name="ScrollButtons"/> in the beginning below FontSize="30" and i get this error "The type local:Imagesgrid was not found.verify that you are not missing an assembly reference"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54559/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-user3660050).